Why aren't all Leviyim Kohanim?
As the firstborn initially served as Kohanim (Onkelos, etc) and the Leviyim were swapped for them (Eg Bamidbar 3) then why are only Aharon and his sons Kohanim and not all of Shevet Levi?

What makes you assume that the firstborns were going to do what Kohanim do, and not what the Levi'im do?

@RabbiKaii משנה זבחים י"ד:ד'
עַד שֶׁלֹּא הוּקַם הַמִּשְׁכָּן, הָיוּ הַבָּמוֹת מֻתָּרוֹת, וַעֲבוֹדָה בַּבְּכוֹרוֹת. מִשֶּׁהוּקַם הַמִּשְׁכָּן, נֶאֶסְרוּ הַבָּמוֹת, וַעֲבוֹדָה בַּכֹּהֲנִים.

@RabbiKaii the word Kohanim is used before the golden calf and the rabbis explained that the word refers to the firstborn.

Aaron and his sons were specifically chosen by Hashem to be Kohanim, not all of the tribe of Levi. If all of the tribe of Levi were Kohanim then who would be the Levi’s? The reason why not all Leviem are Kohanim is because Hashem (after the sin of the calf) only gave Kehuna to Aaron and his sons specifically, your asking why didn’t Hashem make all the Leviim Kohanim since they didn’t participate in the sin either?

@ShtikaK'hodaah When the firstborn lost their privilege and it was transferred to the leviyim then whatever they had should shift over to them leaving all of Shevet Levi as the new kohanim

By the complaints of the Jews after the death of Korach & Co, the Ramban (Bamidbar 17:6) writes that they wanted the "Avodah" - service to go back to the firstborn from the Leviim.
I would guess that both Kohanim and Leviim are includes within "Avodah" of the firstborn. Hashem then chose Aharon from within Levi (and later Pinhas too) just like he gave different jobs in the desert to different families of Leviim. (These 2 degrees of choosing is also implied by Bamidbar Rabbah 3:2, see also Ramban D'varim 10:8).
This is also seen from the Avot 4:13 (with Rambam), were the crown of Kehuna is its own category compared to the crown of Kingship. Just like the whole of the tribe of Yehuda could have been king but God chose David (see I Kings 8:16, Psalms 89:37) from within the tribe.

Can you clarify? I am not denying that the leviyim and kohanim have diff roles. I am merely asking that as the bechorim were the kohanim and it shifted to the leviyim then that should leave all of shevet levi as the new kohanim

The firstborns had the service in the bet hamikdash, not just kehuna. The service includes both, the job of Kohanim and Leviim. The service of the firstborn shifted to the tribe of Levi https://www.sefaria.org/Numbers.3.12. Once it was by Levi, different families got different jobs, Aharon got Kehuna (which could have just as easily gone to Moshe https://www.sefaria.org/Rashi%20on%20Exodus%204:14:1).

You're suggesting that the service of the kohanim (the "avodah") and the service of the leviyim ("avodas avodah") were initially collapsed and set aside for the bechorim exclusively? Do you have any source for that (aside for the "swap" under discussion)?

you see throughout navi how the gob of kohen gadol also went thru families. first elazar (then pinchas), mistake took it to itamar (eli thru evyatar), mistake took it back to elazar (tzadok).

No source, hence the "i would guess".

Interesting idea. So you know, Aharon & sons were selected prior to the bechorim being exchanged for the leviyim.

source? it says to choose aharon as kohen only after egel https://www.sefaria.org/Exodus.28.1. it mentions kohanim by matan torah https://www.sefaria.org/Exodus.19.6, https://www.sefaria.org/Exodus.19.22-24 but as far as i know, no says thats aharons kids

Shevet Levi will be kohanim with coming of moshiyach. The problem is that they lost this right because of the sin of the Golden Calf, becaue they did not protest. Aharon was forced to perform the service, so he was the only one who did not lose his right.
How did shevet Levi get Kehuna? As we know,from Bereshis Rabba 46:5, Abraham was kohen gadol, he got kehuna from Shem. He passed it to Yitzchak, Yitzchak to Yaakov, and Yaakov to Levi (after Reuvein sinned). From here we learn, that Bekhora is different from Kehuna, because Bekhora was given to Yosef.
The exchange in the question is still valid, since with coming of moshiyach the first born will be doing the job of Shevet Levi, and before that they cannot do any service due to the sin of the Golden Calf. (Need help with sources).
